# Como puedo hacer un System.out.println() en XML? (application_context)

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, apache

estoy tratando de hacer un típico System.out.println() en una aplicación Springboot, pero no en una clase java, sino en un application_context.xml, es decir, un tag que cumpla dicha función para ver en que punto del código esta.

No tiene que ser nada complicado, algo así como `<tag>Linea 412</tag>`, y que me muestre ese mensaje hardodeado **"Linea 412"** en la consola (cuando justamente pase por ese código).

El problema es que no se como hacerlo o si es posible sin nada externo (nada de librerías ni loggers extra)

¿Es posible? ¿alguien conoce una manera sencilla?

Gracias!

Comment: ya probaste usando `ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("tag");` o inyectandola mediante `@Value("${tag}") private String tag;`?

Comment: Hola, recuerda que si quieres sugerencias u opiniones puedes obtener reputación para preguntar en [chat], saludos.

Comment: ¿Como podria inyectarlo Ruslan? Agregando esa propiedad @Value al Application.java? estoy un poco perdido y soy nuevo con Spring...